# c# reference correct parameter type

Tags: c#

In Worker.SendMail in the code below, I need to pass a reference of itself to the RetryEmailSend method but am unsure how to reference it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Worker
 {
    public bool SendMail()
    {
        try
        {
            //implementation
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RetryEmailSend(NEED REFERENCE TO THIS INSTANCE Worker.SendMail());
        }
        return true;
    }
 }

 public static class Util
 {
    public static bool RetryAction(Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action"); 

            try { action(); return true; }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
    }

    public static bool RetryEmailSend(NEED INPUT TYPE HERE)
    {
        return Util.RetryAction(() => INPUT TYPE); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `user` even meant to be within `SendMail(user)`? There's no `user` variable in scope as far as I can see...

Comment: There is a lot of this code that is not making any sense. If you wish to provide us with a watered down version of your code, at least make sure that it is valid.

Comment: The `Util` class seems to be pretty reusable for other actions.  And it looks to be written that way.  Why have Email specific methods in it? `RetryEmailSend`?

Comment: @user971823 Where is your `user` defined ?  `RetryEmailSend()` is a static method how can you use `user` variable here(If it is not static).

Comment: It seems to me that `SendActivationEmail` shouldn't know about the retry part - that should be handled by `RetryAction` instead.